# Stack difference between Wasm3 and Emscripten

Tags: c, webassembly

I found that wasm3 and Emscripten handle negative overflow differently. For example, if I call a negative index of an array, wasm3 will return the value at index 0, but Emscripten will return what seem to be values from the stack.

Is this due to protections built into wasm3 that aren’t present in Emscripten, or is it due to how they handle their stacks differently?

Example output

C Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int ar[]={1,2,3,4,5};

int visit(int n){
   return ar[n];
}

int main()
{
   for(int i=6; i>-5;i--){
      printf("Loop num: %d\n",i);
      int temp = visit(i);
      printf("Loop val: %d\n",temp);
   }
}
```

| Emscripten | Wasm3 |
| --- | --- |
| Loop num: 6 Loop val: 5 | Loop num: 6 Loop val: 0 |
| Loop num: 5 Loop val: 0 | Loop num: 5 Loop val: 0 |
| Loop num: 4 Loop val: 5 | Loop num: 4 Loop val: 5 |
| Loop num: 3 Loop val: 4 | Loop num: 3 Loop val: 4 |
| Loop num: 2 Loop val: 3 | Loop num: 2 Loop val: 3 |
| Loop num: 1 Loop val: 2 | Loop num: 1 Loop val: 2 |
| Loop num: 0 Loop val: 1 | Loop num: 0 Loop val: 1 |
| Loop num: -1 Loop val: 117894759 | Loop num: -1 Loop val: 1 |
| Loop num: -2 Loop val: 2457754 | Loop num: -2 Loop val: 1 |
| Loop num: -3 Loop val: 25634578 | Loop num: -3 Loop val: 1 |
| Loop num: -4 Loop val: 85773057694 | Loop num: -4 Loop val: 1 |

Answer (score 1):

Accessing memory which does not belong to the object (in this case accessing array elements outside the bounds) invokes undefined behaviour (UB).

> — An array subscript is out of range, even if an object is apparently
> accessible with the given subscript (as in the lvalue expression
> a[1][7] given the declaration int a[4][5]) (6.5.6).

No behaviour should be expected and there is no guarantee that the same compiler in future releases will behave the same way

> or is it due to how they handle their stacks differently?

C standard does not know anything about the stack. Even implementation using stack will not place static storage duration objects (`ar` in your code) on the stack.